# Formatting inside array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project on which I did all the hard work however I still have some issue that I don't know to do resolve.

I have an array containing row data where each line below represent an array cell and X,Y are variables and may change.

```
x GETFIELD
x PUTFIELD
y GETFIELD
y PUTFIELD
```

I need to find out how many get-field for x and put-field for x and the same for the rest of the variables.

```
x , 1 get-field , 1 put-field

y , 1 get-field , 1 put-field

total get-field:2 , total put-field:2
```

or any format that gives the same analysis.

Comment: you just need to count the occurrences?

Comment: `Collections.frequency` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two maps, one for gets and other for puts. The key will be the variable and the map value will be a counter that will be increased everytime you find an occurrence.

example in pseudocode:

```
declare maps puts and gets
for(items of your array){
    split variable and command
    if command = getfield{
        if (gets.get(variable) == null){
            gets.put(variable,0)
        }
        gets.get(variable)++
    }else{
        if (puts.get(variable) == null){
            puts.put(variable,0)
        }
        puts.get(variable)++
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't get it , can you give an example plz